# Geometric Brownian Motion SDE

Tags: sde

I recently saw the clip : GBM which quantpie made.

here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98xF6b0PZpo

In the time 1:33 of the clip, it naturally said $dX^2 = σ^2X_t^2dt$

To proof this it assumes that there are no random terms.
So it assumes $dX_t = μX_tdt$

My thinking is : $dX_t = μX_tdt+σX_tdB_t$
$dX_t = f_tdt + f_{B_t}dB_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{B_tB_t}dt = df$ (when it is assumed that $f = X_t$)

I mean, I tried to solve the equation using the ito's integral formula but I don't know what to do, because of the term : $X_t$. Should I use ito's formula for ito process..?

To organize my question

1. Why $dX^2 = σ^2X_t^2dt$?
2. Why the assumption $dX_t = μX_tdt$ is reasonable? there was actually random term. And how it could be verified that there are no random term?
3. How can solve differential equation with the formula $df = f_tdt + f_{B_t}dB_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{B_tB_t}dt$

Comment: $(dX_t)^2 = (μX_tdt+σX_tdB_t)^2=$ $μ^2X_t^2(dt)^2+2\mu X_t dtσX_tdB_t +σ^2X_t^2(dB_t)^2$. But $(dt)^2=0,(dt)(dB_t)=0,(dB_t)^2=dt$. So the claimed result follows, the first two terms are zero and the last is $\sigma^2X_t^2 dt$

Comment: They are not "assuming the absence of the random term", they are reminding you how it works in ordinary calculus where there is no random term, to build intuition for how it works in stochastic calculus where the random term is there. It is just an analogy. They should have said "let's first look at a simpler problem..."

Comment: Ach.. just box calculus.. I don't know why I missed it. Thanks for your reply @noob2